# Angular-spinner: functions execution order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spinner

I am pretty new to development and particularly to AngularJS. I have a few slow functions in my app and I would like to show a spinner while the functions are running. I found [Angular-Spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) which should work fine.

I created a div

```
<div ng-show="spinner" class="results_overlay ng-cloak">
    <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
</div>
```

that I put on top of the page

```
.results_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

and that I keep hidden in my controller with:

```
$scope.spinner = false;
```

When a button is pressed I would like to:

1. show the hidden div
2. start the spinner
3. perform the slow operations
4. stop the spinner
5. hide the div again

I am trying with this code:

```
$scope.addDog = function () {
        $scope.spinner = true;
        usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
        $scope.dogs.push({
            id: $scope.dogs.length + 1,
            name: $scope.name,
            age: $scope.age,
            random: $scope.random()
        });

        // Clear input fields after push
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.age = "";
        usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
        $scope.spinner = false;
    };
```

Apparently nothing is happening, playing a bit with the code I understood that the output is pushed on screen altogether and thus the div with the spinner is activated and deactivated at the same time. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

An example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVFgFQajYuhLvKnBZWsZ?p=preview): I am generating a very long sequence of random number to make the function very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never dealt a situation quite like this, and my opinion is that it's bad practice to have code that hangs the browser like this. There is likely a better way to approach your overall goal. Nonetheless, a timeout function will allow the spinner to be displayed before the browser hangs up on the long calculation:

```
$scope.addDog = function () {
    $scope.spinner = true;
    usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
    var myObj = {
      id: $scope.dogs.length + 1,
      name: $scope.name,
      age: $scope.age
    };
    $scope.dogs.push(myObj);
    $timeout(function() {
      myObj.random = $scope.random();
      usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
      $scope.spinner = false;
    });
    // Clear input fields after push
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.age = "";
};
```

You're still overworking the browser, so nothing is guaranteed. Keep in mind that your code even hangs my MSI GS70. Try setting a higher timeout time if you find that the spinner still doesn't get to kick in before the calculations begin.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try today! I actually wanted to hang the browser to test the spinner.
My real project is a Monte Carlo simulation where I need to generate between 500K and 1M random numbers per every single item inserted by the user, calculate the totals, the standard deviation, error and a few more things. It inevitably takes a long time (from half a second to 3-4 seconds). That's why I thought about the spinner...

Comment: Ok just for everyone else´s benefit (as I didn't know, for example :P), to use $timeout, it has to be injected:

`app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$timeout', '$scope', 'usSpinnerService', '$rootScope',
  function($timeout, $scope, usSpinnerService, $rootScope) {
...
}`

Comment: @MirkoG. well sure, variables don't just magic themselves into existence :) But I guess if you're new to Angular, it might be a helpful note.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded, which means when your code is running, the browser (or often these days the tab where your page is rendering) is not updating. This further means that if you block for a long time, the browser will stop responding, which isn't a very good experience for the user (for example, if they resize the window it won't layout the page again until your code finishes running).

The `$timeout` suggestion is okay if you only have an operation that is short but long enough that you want to show some kind of progress notification. However, if you don't know how long your operation could take, a better solution would be to refactor your code to work in an asynchronous manner. You could use a timer to do this, and process a small batch of items every time the timer runs (small enough that it doesn't block the browser). When the processing is complete, you cancel the timer and perform whatever operation you need to do to update your UI/model etc.